# Trabajar en la misma rama y mismo archivo con git

Tags: git

Estoy iniciándome en el mundo de la programación. Todavía no controlo demasiado bien git y me surgen algunos problemas. Si trabajo en mi rama, todo perfecto, lo tengo más o menos controlado. Pero me ha surgido tener que trabajar con otras personas y tocar el mismo archivo.

Al subir cambios, sigo el proceso:

```
git add <nombre_archivos>
git commit -m <mensaje_del_commit> (No sé para qué sirve la opción -a?)
git push origin <nombre_rama>
```

Al subirlo, lógicamente me ha saltado un error: (alguien había hecho cambios)
**¿Se puede ver en qué archivos los hizo mediante algún comando?**

El error:

> ```
> usuario@pc:~/Documentos/Proyecto/API$ git push --set-upstream origin US1875_pulling
> Username for 'https://github.com': user
> Password for 'https://user@github.com': ----
> To https://github.com/RepositorioProyecto
>  ! [rejected]        T1970_Rama -> T1970_Rama (fetch first)
> error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/RepositorioProyecto'
> consejo: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
> consejo: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
> consejo: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
> consejo: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
> consejo: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
> ```

**¿Cómo veo qué archivos ha cambiado antes de bajármelos?** Ahora debería descargar los cambios con:

```
git pull
```

antes de subir los míos, ¿es correcto? Y por último, en caso de haber modificado la misma línea, ¿alguien me puede decir de una manera fácil cómo solucionar el conflicto? Muchas gracias

Comment: No sé mucho de git pero te contesto a esto: *"(No sé para qué sirve la opción -a?)"* Con `git commit -a` te saltas el paso de añadir los archivos con `git add`: https://git-scm.com/book/es/v1/Fundamentos-de-Git-Guardando-cambios-en-el-repositorio#Salt%C3%A1ndote-el-%C3%A1rea-de-preparaci%C3%B3n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entiendo que lo que estás buscando hacer es un [diff](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#git-diff-Variouswaystocheckyourworkingtree):

```
$ git diff HEAD
```

Espero y te sirva